# How can I setup my opencv 4.1.2 library on Xcode?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am having some problems installing the opencv 4.1.2 library on Xcode on my mac
When I type using namespace cv it becomes blue(accepted) but when I write even the simplest program and run it I get back build fail.

Screen of the error:
[image: Screen of the error]

Comment: int waitKey(int delay=0), waitKey accept a delay in milliseconds, not a key value.

Comment: do you notice any other error in the code and more in specific in the initial include part?

Comment: it says opencv2/opencv.hpp not found but I really can't understand why

Comment: The absolute path is "/Users/Als/Documents/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp", you miss     the first forward slash. It is better to use relative path and set header search paths in  Xcode project build settings.

Comment: May I ask you how you learnt open cv for c++?

Comment: Although I'm not good at open cv, I would like to help you with c++ problem.

Comment: This is my email: alesalvini@gmail.com. contact me here, i would really appreciate your help

Comment: My email: brianchenhacker@gmail.com